# What the correlation between GCC and OpenMP versions?

Tags: gcc, openmp

I'd like to know if there is a way to know OpenMP version given GCC version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As of GCC 4.2, the compiler implements version 2.5 of the OpenMP specification, as of 4.4 it implements version 3.0 and since GCC 4.7 it supports the OpenMP 3.1 specification. GCC 4.9 supports OpenMP 4.0 for C/C++, GCC 4.9.1 also for Fortran. GCC 5 adds support for Offloading.

from https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/openmp